# Missing model whilst viewing in active camera

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Wonder if someone could help? Whilst viewing a simple pulley model in active camera view, I can only see the foremost part of the model. What am I doing wrong?

Much appreciate any help.

[image]

I attach a pic of the full model in 3D View.

[image: Full model in 3D View]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value of your camera clipping in the *Properties Panel* <kbd>N</kbd>. At the top of the Panel you should see a section called *Clip*. Increase the *End* value and this should fix your problem.[image]

Comment: Changing the clipping End value from the properties panel, this for some reason never worked, however tried the properties of the camera (select camera first) which also has a clipping section under the 'Lens' properties. I adjusted that and gave me the full model. Updating the Lens End clipping properties does not update on the Properties Panel, it still shows a value of 1m. Should this not update?

Comment: I believe that these two are independent, similar like that you can control the subdivision surface levels for both the viewport and render independently.